# What web framework supports Ctrl+Shift+G into presentation layer?

Tags: java, eclipse, thymeleaf

In Eclipse, Ctrl+Shift+G is a quick way to search for all references to a method or member variable.

When using Thymeleaf, references from the template into the Java code are not included in the search results. The reason is well understood: the coupling is very indirect, and cannot be reliably determined.

Is there a Web Framework which has close enough coupling to the Java code, that a Ctrl+Shift+G will show references from the template?

Comment: Decoupling has advantages. So would tool support for the framework used instead be a better solution? For example, how [Spring Tools 4](https://spring.io/tools) does it ([as you can see here in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW245OV_WE4)).

Comment: Interesting. Which web framework(s) does it work with?

Comment: I think this is feature that is provided by the plugin of the template language in Eclipse, and not by the web frameworks plugin. I'm quite sure it works for JSP by the way.